# Stored procedure which checks the password and login with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure to verify the password and login and to select my columns from table `[Utilisateur]` and it worked. But I wanted to select another table `[Adresse]` (which has FK `IdUtilisateur`) in the same time. I tried to use inner join, but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Check_Password]
    @login VARCHAR (16),
    @password NVARCHAR(32)
AS
    DECLARE @hPassword VARBINARY(32)
    DECLARE @salt CHAR(8)
    DECLARE @newPassword VARBINARY(32)

    SELECT @salt = salt, @hPassword = Password 
    FROM Utilisateur 
    WHERE login = @login

    SELECT @newPassword = dbo.SF_EncryptedPassword (@password, @salt)

    IF (@newPassword = @hPassword)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT [Login], Nom, Prenom, DateNaiss, Photo, Email, Rue, Ville, Numero, CP 
        FROM Utilisateur 
        INNER JOIN Adresse ON Utilisateur.IdUtilisateur = Adresse.IdUtilisateur 
        WHERE login = @login 
    END
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: In the view I've only properties form my table Utilisateur and the rest is null

Comment: Side note (if this is for **SQL Server**): you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Yes it is for SQL Server. Thank's!

Comment: As-is, the code looks good. Please show the table structures, and if views are used include their definitions as well.

Comment: I finally founded the problem, it was in my views.